# Torque considered about different points in a system

Tags: torque

If we consider the torque about point A, there is none, so there is no rotation about point A. If we consider torque about point B, there is a net torque which means that there is rotation about point B. But if there is rotation about point B, doesn't this imply that there must also be rotation about every single other point?

[image: here]

Are there specific locations where I can take torque about, or have I simply made a mistake in logic?

Comment: When you say total torque what exactly do you mean? As in total torque about which point? (I thought torque was relative, but apparently I have some gaping flaws in my torque knowledge)

Comment: Conventionally torque is taken about the rotation axis, but you may not know what that is. So take a mass-weighted average of the torque about every point in the entire system. The centre of mass will appear...

Comment: Usually I would take the torque about the centre of mass, but today I was feeling wild so I thought I'd try other points and the results are strange, I don't see what's wrong intrinsically about taking torques about other points?

Comment: The edit needs to be rejected. I clicked the approve button by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is check torques **about the center of mass** to check for rotational motion. In this case there is torque about the center of the square and thus there is going to be rotation.

The only case where the point of summing up torques does not matter is when the net forces are zero. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/111348/392.