# Torque parallel with a principal axis

Tags: torque, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

Introduction: Suppose I have a rigid body with the inertia matrix in the initial position $I_0$ . If the body fixed coordinate axis rotate with matrix $R$ then it's inertia matrix will be $I_B = R^T I_0 R$. Suppose the eigenvectors of $I_0$ are $\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2, \vec{v}_3$. Being principal axis they are orthgonal. Then $R^T v_1$ is an eigenvector of $I_B$.

Question: if a torque $T_c$ parallel with $R^T v_1$is applied at the center of mass, will the body have an angular velocity also parallel with $R^T v_1$ ? That is: will $\omega \times T_c = 0$ knowing that $I_B T_c = \lambda_1 T_c$ ?

I think the answer is yes, but I am unable to prove it ... 
I know that $T_c = \omega \times (I_B \omega) + I_B \dot{\omega}$ I tried to show $\omega \times T_c = 0$ but $\omega \times T_C = \omega (\omega^T I_B \omega) - I_B\omega (\omega^T \omega) + \omega \times I_B\omega$. I do not know how to proceed ...

Of course, if $\omega$ is a principal axis, then $T_c = I_B \dot{\omega}$ is also an eigenvector of $I_B$, but I am interested if the converse is true ...

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I would appreciate a positive feedback, logic and math. Please if possible give that ...

Comment: Is $T_c$ in same coordinates as $I_0$ or $I_B$?

Comment: It is easy to show that when the rotation axis is along a principal direction then the angular momentum is parallel to said axis. And torque is the rate of change of angular momentum.

Comment: $T_C$ is in the same coordinate as $I_B$ ... I just realised that my notations are a little confusing ... Yes the torque is the rate of change of angular momentum, but what I know is that $\dot{L}$ is a principal axis. Does this always mean that $L$ is also a principal axis? If so, why?

Answer (score 2):

The the equations of motion on the body frame are

$$ \vec{T}_B =  \mathrm{I}_B \dot{\vec{\omega}}_B + \vec{\omega}_B \times \mathrm{I}_B \vec{\omega}_B  $$

or in component form

$$ \begin{pmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_2 \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{vmatrix} I_{1} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & I_{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & I_{3} \end{vmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{\omega}_1 \\ \dot{\omega}_2 \\\dot{\omega}_2 
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} 
 0 & -\omega_3 & \omega_2 \\
\omega_3 & 0 & -\omega_1 \\
-\omega_2 & \omega_1 & 0
\end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix} I_{1} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & I_{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & I_{3} \end{vmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
{\omega}_1 \\ {\omega}_2 \\ {\omega}_2 
\end{pmatrix}  $$

where $1$, $2$ and $3$ are the principal directions. I think your question is what happens if a torque is applied along a principal direction? The problem is that only angular *acceleration* depends on torque and angular velocity is usually defined in direction by the kinematics. So you can't ask *If I apply a torque, what will the speed be*?

In any case suppose the general case where $T_1 \neq 0$ and $T_2 = T_3 = 0$

$$\begin{aligned}
  T_1 & = I_1 \dot{\omega}_1 + (I_3-I_2) \omega_2 \omega_3 \\
  0 & = I_2 \dot{\omega}_2 + (I_2-I_3) \omega_1 \omega_3 \\
  0 & = I_3 \dot{\omega}_3 + (I_2-I_1) \omega_1 \omega_2 
\end{aligned} $$

So you are trying to understand what motions obey the above equations of motion. Assuming the general case of $I_1 \neq I_2 \neq I_3$ you see that the torque along $1$ does not affect the angular acceleration along $2$ and $3$. So a torque applied along a principal axis, will accelerate the body also along the principal axis only if the body is already rotating along the same axis already. Only when $\omega_2 = \omega_3 =0$ you decouple the system to

$$\begin{aligned}
  T_1 & = I_1 \dot{\omega}_1\\
  \dot{\omega}_2 & = 0\\
  \dot{\omega}_3 & = 0
\end{aligned} $$

Comment: First of all: thank you so much for your answer! I will use the same meaning of $R$ as you did (I usually use $R^T $ in the sens you seem to use $R$), so: I think the rotation being about $\omega$ axis it is true that $\omega_c = R\cdot \omega_c = R^T \cdot \omega_c$ and the same for $\dot{\omega}_c$ but yes this will also yield $R T_B = R (\omega_B \times (I_B \omega_B) + I_B \dot{\omega}_B)$ and yes if $\omega_C = \omega_B$ is a principal axis then $T_B = I_B \dot{\omega}_B$. What I am not able to prove to my self, is your last proposition: "In addition if the torque ..." why is this? Why ?

Comment: If $\dot{\vec{\omega}}$ is along principal axis then $\vec{T} = \mathrm{I} \dot{\vec{\omega}} = \lambda \dot{\vec{\omega}}$ which is  obviously parallel to $\dot{\vec{\omega}}$

Comment: Also, it is common convention to represent the rotation matrix $\mathrm{R}$ as in $(\mbox{local}) \rightarrow (\mbox{global})$ transformation. That is, it transforms local vectors (body coordinates) to global vectors (world coordinates).

Comment: Yes, if assuming $\omega$ is a principal axis then $T$ is also a principal axis, that I wrote inside the question, but I am interested in the converse ... How can I prove that if $T$ is along a principal axis, then also $\omega$ is ...

Comment: Because if $T$ and $\dot{\omega}$ are related _with a scalar value_. By definition they are parallel.

Comment: I think I understand the question better now. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer! I think that the equation $T_B = \omega \times (I_B \omega) + I_B \dot{\omega}$ can be seen as a differential equation with the unknown $\omega$, hence after "integration" $\omega$ will depend upon the initial conditions. (therefore I can ask what will $\omega$ be, given an initial $\omega_0$.) Supposing zero initial conditions it seems safe to say that $\omega$ will also be a principal axis ... right?

Comment: If initial conditions are zero then $\omega=0$

Comment: Sir I would like to say more, but I get a message from this site, suggesting to  move this discussion to chat (whatever that would be). Is it ok if I do so?

Comment: You can safely ignore the suggestion to move to a chat. If you want to add more information to your question or to clarify it, I suggest you edit the question and _add_ it there.

Comment: Well I want to say that I do not understand why you say that if the initial conditions are zero then $\omega = 0$. That would probably be true if $T_B = 0$, that is in case of a homogeneous diff eq which is not the case here. I mean, if the rigid body is not moving before applying a torque along a principal axis, then it will also not move after applying the torque ?? But I have actually another bigger problem, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/311593/torque-off-center-of-mass-rigid-body which I am attempting to solve with the present question. Would you please have a look at it?

Comment: $\omega$ is part of the initial conditions. For dynamical systems positions and velocities need to be specified as initial conditions.