# Length of rod given forces and lengths to calculate torque

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, torque

In the question and solution given below, I haven't understood why is the solution asking us to take torques about the center of mass.
In my approach I equated the net torque about the lower end B of the rod to zero

[image]

MY APPROACH:

let distance between line of action of F<sub>2</sub> and B = k cm

then length of the rod = k+20 cm

taking torques about B, we have
F<sub>2</sub>k - F<sub>1</sub>(k+20) = 0 (since rod is only translating)

Putting F<sub>2</sub> as 5N , and F<sub>1</sub> as 3N, we have k=30cm

thus my answer comes out as 50cm

*ps : we cant take F<sub>1</sub> as 7N. I already tried that. torque being zero is impossible in that case

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93698/ 
I hope this helps

Comment: Hello and welcome to the physics stack exchange! Since this is not a typical help site, it would be great to ask questions to benefit the wider audience.

Comment: You can refer to this link for more details : [How to ask homework type questions on this site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).
 In case you find these rules to be a bit harsh, you can always [go to any other suitable sites](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

As someone said before, you can learn the alphabet from these sites and then come back here to ask questions about dinosaurs :)
Have a great time!

Comment: @AlphaLife this isn't my home work question. i am not able to understand the concept of torque behind it.....as in, which point to take and why

Comment: @S.M. tnx. it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only sum torques about any point and expect them all to be the same if and only if the body is in **translational and rotational** equilibrium.

Let $A$ and $B$ be two point on some body. Let $\vec \tau $ denote the torque, and $\Sigma \vec F$ be the net force. Then, the torque about A is related to the torque about point B by the following equation
$$\vec \tau_B = \vec \tau _A + \vec r_{AB} \times \Sigma \vec F$$

This body **will rotate about its center of mass**, so to break down the motion in rotational and translational motion, you should consider the translation of the center of mass and rotation about the center of mass.

See here: [Why if the torque equals zero measured from one point in space it equals zero measured from any other point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93698/why-if-the-torque-equals-zero-measured-from-one-point-in-space-it-equals-zero-me).

Comment: understood ;) thank you

Comment: but do you mean to say that the body given in the question is NOT in rotational equilibrium ? is so, why ? isnt it NOT rotating ?

Comment: @omjoglekar rotational equilibrium is when the net torque is zero, which, in this case, it is not. I'll also add that calculating the torque about a point other than the center of mass will (when the body is in equilibrium) sometimes offer a much quicker solution, you just have to be sure that the net force and torques are zero